# How to perfectly sync clock app widget with system clock in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, android-manifest, android-broadcast

I made a digital clock widget which is using `AlarmManager` to update the time every 60 seconds.

```
@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);
    Log.d("onEnabled","Widget Provider enabled.  Starting timer to update widget every minute");
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), 60000, createClockTickIntent(context));
}
```

The problem is, polling the system time every 60 seconds does not sync my widget time with system time. lets say user adds widget at 6:00:20, my widget shows the time 6:00 and sleeps for 60 seconds, so when system time becomes 6:01:00, my widget needs another 20 seconds to catch up.

Is there a way to do the following ?

> - **step 1**: get system time and show on widget.
> - **step 2**: set the first update interval = (60 - current Seconds value).
> - **step 3**: after first update, set the subsequent update intervals to 60 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intercept the [`ACTION_TIME_TICK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_TICK) broadcast. This broadcast action is sent on every minute change of the local time zone clock.

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver;

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context)
{
    super.onEnabled();
    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent)
        {
            if (intent.getAction().compareTo(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK) == 0) {
                // update widget time here using System.currentTimeMillis()
            }
        }
    };

    context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context)
{
    super.onDisabled();
    if (receiver != null)
        context.getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```

**Further considerations:**

- We could have tried catching the `ACTION_TIME_TICK` broadcast in the `AppWidgetProvider` class' `onReceive()` method (after adding the action to the `intent-filter` in the manifest) but the documentation states that this broadcast action can only be intercepted by a `BroadcastReceiver` registered programmatically. Still, this may be worth a try.
- It is not that using a `BroadcastReceiver` is "better" than using the `AlarmManager`. Different approaches are required in different situations, and since the `ACTION_TIME_TICK` broadcast is sent by the system, why not exploit that ?

Comment: Thanks ZygoteInit, is BradcastReceiver better than AlarmManager for clock widgets?

Comment: I tried this - and it worked great for about 10 minutes - but then the system shuts down my process and it stops working... :-(

Comment: @DeNitE: This worked perfectly for me in an app widget project that I had worked on previously. If you could explain your problem in detail, preferably in another question, I'd be more than happy to help ... :)

Comment: @Y.S. I think i figured it out - I made a Service to update the widget that is START_STICKY to ensure it doesn't get shut down. Works great now! :-)

Comment: @DeNitE: That is precisely what I was gonna suggest ... :)

Comment: @Y.S. I have the same problem as you, could you post your result? it would be a life saver!

Comment: @SaharPournasseh when you intercept the action time tick broadcast, start a Service from onReceive() and update the widget.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question but using BroadcastReceiver with `ACTION_TIME_TICK` on Android Oreo and above won't work anymore. An better alternative for **API Level 17+** would be to use `TextClock` which is supported by `RemoteViews`. Just add something like this in your clock widget layout:

```
<TextClock
        android:id="@+id/widget_clock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="56sp"
        tools:text="12:45"
        <!-- You can also easily add custom typefaces -->
        android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand_regular"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
```

The clock should sync automatically with the system clock.

Comment: Would it work for calendar? Or for calendar simply use textview?

Comment: And what if I want separation between hour and minutes? For example hour has bigger font and minutes has smaller fonts?

Comment: For calendar you would need to set the set24HourFormat() and set12HourFormat() to the date format you want. If you want to have different sizes for hour and minute you will need two textclocks one with format HH and the other with mm (for 24h Hour:Minute) and set the textsize respectively.