# How long does a BroadcastReceiver stay active if it is registered in an AppWidgetProvider?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

I'm registered a `BroadcastReceiver` for the `ACTION_TIME_TICK` inside my `AppWidgetProvider` to update a clock every minute. Like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29346663/962638):

AFAIK a BroadcastReceiver that is registered at runtime is only active as long as the application is running.
But from my understanding the AppWidgetProvider could get garbage collected at any time and it doesn't have a real lifecycle anyway.

For the last 30 minutes this has been working great but is this really (still?) a viable method?
How long will the BroadcastReceiver stay registered in theory?

---

Update:
I simulated a ram shortage with a memory filler app and checked the list of running processes with `adb shell ps -A`. Once the process was terminated the updates to the clock did in fact stop.

Comment: As an alternative, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46058966/2921519 suggests using TextClock. Since that widget updates itself without the need for your app process to be alive, it is a more robust alternative if your use case can fit within its restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How long will the BroadcastReceiver stay registered in theory?

For as long as your process is running. How long your process will remain running varies widely based on environment (amount of system RAM, number of installed applications doing background work by one means or another, whether the user is actively using the device and flipping between other apps, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, what confused me was that the AppWidgetProvider and the Activities share a process and just the UI is rendered by the home screen's process. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016944/does-an-android-widget-run-in-the-same-process-as-its-app